# Does anybody know a real life example of IronRuby usage

Tags: .net, ruby, ironruby

Although I'm not a .NET developer I always get excited about the work DLR team is doing at Microsoft. I watched a couple of videos from various Ruby conferences where John Lam showed the progress of IronRuby and Dynamic Language Runtime in general. The latest video I saw is from Ruby conf: http://rubyconf2008.confreaks.com/ironruby.html

Despite the fact that it's not fully compatible with a standard Ruby 1.8 implementation it looks pretty good and the .NET integration is very impressive. I wonder if someone used it in some real life projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using it to test the main WPF-based app used by journalists at the BBC... (an ironruby/cucumber/bewildr combination).

Answer (score 3):

IronRuby is used for the dialplans in the [mysipswitch](http://www.mysipswitch.com) SIP server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it in the new [AppMakerX](http://www.appmakerx.com/) code generator, which is being refined at present in a major consulting project prior to commercial release in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It may tough to find a real world example at this stage as I don't believe that it has got to a production ready release yet.

Comment: Probably worth removing this answer now... :)

Answer (score 0):

Some people have used it in real world applications. And I include a bunch of samples with my book. for example in my github account you can find a mocker for ironruby, as well as an ironruby mvc implementation. My account is casualjim on github
in the github account of thbar you'll find some more ironruby and .net stuff